# Pointer to a struct that has a fixed array of another struct

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to write C# bindings for a native DLL. In the DLL are structs defined as

```
typedef struct Foo {
    Bar bars[32];
} Foo;
```

and

```
typedef struct Bar {
    uint32_t data;
} Bar;
```

and a function

```
void Baz(Foo* foo);
```

Ideally, I would like to define the C# structs as

```
public unsafe struct Foo {
    public unsafe fixed Bar bars[32]
}
```

and

```
public struct Bar {
    public uint data;
}
```

and the function as

```
public unsafe void BazDelegate(Foo* foo);
```

This would allow me to use pointers to manipulate the structs. However, this is not allowed because fixed arrays can only be used on primitive types, so I can't have a fixed array of the second type. The API requires that the first type be passed in via pointer to a certain function.

The only solution I've found is by changing the type of the field to a managed array, `Bar[]`, and letting the marshaller take care of it. But then that means that I can' take a pointer the the struct. So I would have to change the function's signature from unsafe pointer to `ref`.

The bindings are not written using `[DllImport]`. They are loaded at runtime through `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`. Could I change the structs to use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]` and the function use `ref Foo` instead of `Foo*`?

Is using a function created from `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` considered P/Invoke? Do managed arrays still get marshalled if they aren't passed through `[DllImport]`? Do they get marshalled if passed by `ref`?

Comment: It's good that you made your question simpiler, but you should now include a note that this is for interacting with a graphics API so you are using the unsafe methods and types to get the maximum speed possible. Otherwise you will just get a bunch of answers saying "Stop using unsafe methods and types unnecessarily"

Comment: If you really want to unsafe and pointers then design the unmanaged code to facilitate that.

Comment: The unmanaged layer is Vulkan, a graphics API. I have no control over it